# Other ways to say a project is ahead of schedule?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

I'm looking for ways to say a business project is (or will be) completed ahead of schedule. Obviously, there are plenty of phrases for delayed or on-time statuses, but what are some phrases for describing those rare situations when a project is actually ready ahead of time?

This is what I've come up with so far:

- completed sooner than expected
- have some time to spare
- done ahead of schedule

Are there any other ways to say that Murphy's Law didn't apply this one time, and things actually went better than expected?

Comment: What is wrong with the phrases you listed?

Comment: @bib Nothing is wrong with them. I'm literally searching for several ways to say the same thing. :) (and sadly, it's not my project that's on time... mine are always delayed ;) )

Answer (score 2):

Metaphorically, the concept "ahead of schedule" can be communicated with a sense of tentative optimism:

> We've enjoyed favorable winds on this project so far, and the forecast
>   seems encouraging.

Answer (score 1):

First, a human nature note.

You never know what might go haywire at the tail end of a project.  So always under-promise.   :-)

That said, try the following:

"Tasks are progressing under the more optimistic time estimates."
"We are likely to complete the project earlier than anticipated."
"Contingencies built into the project plan are likely to remain un-needed."
"Fewer then expected changes and challenges have facilitated rapid progress."

Comment: HEH some great phrases there.  "transitional time-wise negative factors have been non-appearancewise dominant!"

Answer (score 1):

Focusing on what's most important to the client, I'd go with this:

> "The project seems to be ahead of schedule.  Though there's always the possibility of an unanticipated delay, we'll remain diligent yet optimistic."